# How to prevent users to create account with an email that is already taken in Drupal 8 ?

Tags: drupal-8

I don't understand why but the Drupal 8 core registration form allow to creates a new account with an email address that is already taken !

How can I prevent this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked this problem in my Drupal 8 installation but i can't find this problem.

But if you get this problem then create a custom form validation through [hook_form_alter](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiAuoHpr7jTAhXHpI8KHUx3CRsQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fapi%2Fdrupal%2Fcore%2521lib%2521Drupal%2521Core%2521Form%2521form.api.php%2Ffunction%2Fhook_form_alter%2F8.2.x&usg=AFQjCNGbwxauAfNRi67Ang3XSzPoX-tQdQ) in user register form.

```
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){

 if($form_id == 'user_register_form'){
   $form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_validate';
 }

}

$form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_validate';
```

and check this user email exist in database through [user_load_by_mail](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj99azhsLjTAhUBMY8KHRmZDRoQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fapi%2Fdrupal%2Fcore!modules!user!user.module%2Ffunction%2Fuser_load_by_mail%2F8.2.x&usg=AFQjCNG892GYG39H_20tdzKfxDuBKAjoxA) function

if user exist then set form error "The email address is already taken."

I hope it may be useful for you.